# Generating call graphs for standard library calls in doxygen?

Tags: c++, c, doxygen

I have this problem with doxygen. When i generate the documentation of my code, sometimes i need find the callers for a specific standard library calls like strcpy. what i need is a graph that shows each function that calls for example strcpy or printf.

I think one way to solve this problem is by copying the include files of libc into my source directory but this is not so practical solution. Is there anyway to generate such graph without copying the include files ??

Answer (score 0):

Doxygen only creates Inheritance diagram for the classes/methods in your documentation. There are addons that allow you to create entire graphs but I dont think they will include library functions.

Comment: Can you link to one of these addons? Or name them at least?

Comment: Graphviz for one. Unfortunately i havent been doing this work for a long time so I dont know any more.

Comment: Graphviz is used without adding anything on... well, never mind.

Comment: Yes. But its output can be plugged into Doxygen to include in the documentation.